# PHP/MySQL - Imprimir valores com relação entre tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, modelo-relacional

Em um sistema eu preciso imprimir latas de tinta e cada uma tem suas próprias cores. Fiz de uma forma que funciona, porém repete diversas vezes os requests no banco de dados.

Fiz duas tabelas(Exemplo):

```
latas
______________
id | nome
1  | uso geral
2  | teste 1
3  | teste 2


cores
__________________________
id | nome | hexa | id_lata
1  | azul | #0495| 1
2  | preto | #000| 1
```

Meu código está mais ou menos assim no momento:

```
<?php
$sql_latas = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM latas');
while($row_latas = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_latas)){
?>
   <div class="lata">
      <span><?php echo $row_latas['nome']; ?></span>
   </div>

   <ul class="cores">

      <?php
      $sql_cores = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM cores WHERE id_lata = '.$row_latas['id']);
      while($row_cores = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_cores)){
      ?>

         <li><?php echo $row_cores['nome']; ?></li>

      <?php
      }
      ?>

   </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode elaborar apenas um SQL, usando o JOIN para unir as tabelas com base no `id_lata`, neste caso, você conseguirá obter os resultados de cada uma das tabelas, e também para distinguir uma coluna da outra, você pode no SELECT, setar qual é a coluna e qual será o nome dela representada, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT 
    latas.nome as nome_lata,
    cores.nome as cor_lata,
FROM latas
JOIN cores ON(cores.id_lata=latas.id)


while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo $row['nome_lata'];
    echo $row['cor_lata']."<br><br>";
}
```